# Calculate the form group control value according the values of other controls Using angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular7, formgroups

I've a form field called "totalMembers". It's value will be the sum of some member types (like number of child, number of students..etc) which we are selecting. So it should be dynamically change it's value and display on the window on same time itself. I would like to know, is there any way to write a custom method inside the formgroup itself (like custom validation) to update it's value.

Following is my form group

```
testform: FormGroup;

this.testform = this.formBuilder.group({
      numberofchildren: [0, Validators.required],
      numberofstudents: [0, Validators.required],
      handicapped: [0, Validators.required],
      numberoftestnumbers: [0, Validators.required],
      totalMembers: [0, Validators.required],
      comments: ['', Validators.required],
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subcribe valueChanges event, like this:

```
this.testform.get('numberofchildren').valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
  // code logic here
  this.updateForm.get('totalMembers').setValue('something');
  this.updateForm.get('totalMembers').updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
});
this.testform.get('numberofstudents').valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
  // code logic here
  this.updateForm.get('totalMembers').setValue('something');
  this.updateForm.get('totalMembers').updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
});
// others form control ...
```

Other way, you can binding `ngModel` and use `ngModelChange` event